# How to handle authorization with DotNetBrowser user control?

Tags: authentication, authorization, dotnetbrowser

I could't figure out loading urls that requires authentication with DotNetBrowser control.

IE and Chrome browsers display a dialog and asks for a user name and a password.
But DotNetBrowser displays the text below :

> HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied

How can I make DotNetBrowser show a login dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following article explains how to handle HTTP authentication in DotNetBrowser:

https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110052-handling-basic-digest-and-ntlm-authentication

In two words, it is necessary to implement and register a custom implementation of the `NetworkDelegate` interface in order to provide user name and password when necessary. For example:

```
public class CustomNetworkDelegate : DefaultNetworkDelegate 
{
    public bool OnAuthRequired(AuthRequiredParams parameters)
    {
         if (!parameters.IsProxy) {
            parameters.Username = "proxy-username";
            parameters.Password = "proxy-password";
            // Don't cancel authentication
            return false;
        }
    // Cancel authentication
    return true;
    }
}
```

This implementation is then registered as shown below:

```
browserView.Browser.Context.NetworkService.NetworkDelegate = new CustomNetworkDelegate();
```

It is possible to show the dialog or to handle authentication in the application code directly. You can also register the existing implementations (`WinFormsDefaultNetworkDelegate` or `WPFDefaultNetworkDelegate`) that contain ready-to-use authentication dialogs.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361999/reachout-to-dotnetbrowser